# How to see if an AWS Aurora serveless cluster is paused?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I'm using an AWS Aurora serverless PostgreSQL cluster and have activated the "pause after 5 minutes of inactivity" option as my load is unevenly distributed during the day.

I made sure no connection is left opened on the cluster and I thus believe the entire cluster should be turned off after 5 minutes.

But I can't seem to find a place in the AWS console for RDS that shows me the current state of my cluster, either being "live" or "paused".

I mean, there is the Status/Info section that says "available" but it never changes, despite my connections being down to 0 for 10 minutes before one connection is made again, as can be seen on the following Cloudwatch capture:

[image: Connections]

What have I missed?

Thanks a lot for any pointers/clues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Aurora Serverless V1, we are charged based on no of [ACUs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.how-it-works.html#aurora-serverless.how-it-works.pause-resume) used.

Since you have checked pause compute after 5 minutes, we should see ACU to go down to 0.
[image] .

[ServerlessDatabaseCapacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Monitoring.html) is the metric we need to look at to confirm the capacity goes down to 0 after 5 minutes of in-activity i.e 5 minutes after connections goes down to 0.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the metric that I was looking for.
It was never going to 0 until a fellow developer remembered that there is a "health check" task that connects to the database every 10 seconds.
It's doing it so fast that I could not see it on the AWS console, but it was definitely preventing the pause from occurring.

Comment: @OBones Awesome! Glad you were able to spot the right one that is keeping it alive.